# Stretch-fill menu item header in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to stretch-fill menu item header content? I mean something like this:

```
<Menu>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <Ellipse Fill="Red" MinWidth="20" MinHeight="20"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Ellipse Fill="Green" MinWidth="20" MinHeight="20" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Menu>
```

Ellipses are just 20x20...

Comment: Are you missing some xaml? Are you maybe looking for [MenuItem.HeaderTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @ChrisW. I did try providing ItemContainerStyle, ItemTemplate, Header, HeaderTemplate - nothing helps. It after substituting ItemsControl instead of Menu, but I am looking for a menu behavior here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu puts each `Ellipse` inside a `MenuItem`, and the default `MenuItem` template doesn't allow its content to stretch. Therefore, you need to override that template, via `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<Menu>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- New MenuItem template: -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Border Background="Gold" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Margin="1" >
                            <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    <Ellipse Fill="Red" MinWidth="20" MinHeight="20"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Ellipse Fill="Green" MinWidth="20" MinHeight="20" 
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Menu>
```